# Cannot convert var type to list object

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am storing the returned items to the var type and then trying it to bind with the list object which is of model class type. But while doing so it gives an error saying that,

> cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.collections.generic.list<AnonymousType>` to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<MyService.Models.EmpModel>`

Please help me resolve this issue.

```
public IEnumerable<EmpModel> GetEmpDetailsById(int id)
{
    var EmpList = (from a in EmpDet 
    where a.EmpId.Equals(id) 
    select new { a.EmpId, a.Name, a.City });

    List<EmpModel> objList = new List<EmpModel>();
    objList = EmpList.ToList(); // gives error here

    return objList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one statement

```
return (from a in EmpDet 
    where a.EmpId.Equals(id) 
    select new EmpModel 
               { EmpId = a.EmpId, 
                 Name = a.Name, 
                 City = a.City 
               }).ToList();

}
```

Comment: thank u...it worked out for me

Answer (score 1):

The type of the objList is `List<EmpModel>` but you are returning a `List` of [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types). You can change it like this:

```
var EmpList = (from a in EmpDet 
    where a.EmpId.Equals(id) 
    select new EmpModel { EmpId = a.EmpId, Name = a.Name, City = a.City });
```

And if you still get error probably it is because you cannot project onto a mapped entity then you need to create a DTO class with needed properties from the `EmpModel` entity like this:

```
public class TestDTO
{
    public string EmpId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can:

```
select new TestDTO { EmpId = a.EmpId, Name = a.Name }
```